# Induction of semantics for grammars of natural languages (as opposed to syntax)

Tags: computational-linguistics, grammar, generative-grammar, dependency-grammar, universal-grammar

I am learning about combinatory categorial grammars and the formal semantics of natural language, course by Partee http://people.umass.edu/partee/MGU_2005/MGU05_formal_semantics.htm (especially lecture http://people.umass.edu/partee/MGU_2005/MGU052.pdf is relevant for this question) is great indtroduction into these themes.

So - there are syntax rules and semantic rules from natural language (e.g. English) and general principles that allows us to make semantic rules from the syntactic rules. There is some literature about supervised or even unsupervised learning of combinatory categorial grammars and this literature specifically deals with the induction of syntactic rules.

My question is - **are there literature, efforts, developments about supervised or unsupervised induction of semantics/semantic rules for natural language?**

Comment: This is a very vague and general question. Please make it more specific.

Comment: @Adam_G The question can be rephrased: *How can I teach a machine to think?*.

Comment: That is even more vague and general

Comment: Tomorrow I will state the problem mathematically, this is quite mainstream question.